# OC4J Problem: global-web-application.xml Works, orion-web.xml Doesn't

Tags: oc4j

I recently "solved" a somewhat common problem in OC4J regarding the use of Xerces rather than OC4J's built-in parser. The problem was solved by adding this line to global-web-application.xml:

`<web-app-class-loader search-local-classes-first="true"/>`

Unfortunately, this was too much of a big-hammer approach that could cause problems on the app server, so I tried to resolve it via creating the following orion-web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory of the app:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>

<orion-web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/orion-web-10_0.xsd">

<web-app-class-loader search-local-classes-first="true" include-war-manifest-class-path="true"/>

      <web-app/>

</orion-web-app>`

Unfortunately, it turns out that using global-web-application.xml worked, using orion-web.xml didn't

OC4J version is 10.1.3.5.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is specify at Deploy Time. Take a look:

Specifying search-local-classes-first at Deployment Time

The following example illustrates how to set the search-local-classes-first attribute in the orion-web.xml file generated for the Web module at deployment time, with Application Server Control.

1. Select Applications>Deploy to launch the Application Server Control deployment wizard.
2. Supply the path to the application in the first page of the wizard.
3. Specify the application name and supply any context URI mappings in the second page.
4. Click Configure Class Loading in the third page of the wizard (Deploy: Deployment Settings).
5. Under Configure Web Module Class Loaders, check the Search Local Classes First checkbox next to the name of the Web module containing the local JAR file to use.
6. Optionally click the Save Deployment Plan button, and save the plan for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this in a different manner. Using properties, and removing libraries.

There are two properties:

**xml.driver.property**

**xml.driver.impl**

One define the parser interface and the other the implementation. You can switch this from one implementation from another.

for example we have:

*xml.driver.property=org.xml.sax.driver*

*xml.driver.impl=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser*

As this is a system properties you can load it in many different ways. We use a special servlet installed in all OC4J instances (containers) that loads this an other properties at runtime.

A "little" bit late but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm abble run JAXB2 (used by Spring WS 2.1.4) on my OC4J 10.13 (and 10.13.50). JAXB needs xalan lib.

orion-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE orion-web-app PUBLIC "-//Evermind//DTD Orion Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ias/dtds/orion-web.dtd">

<orion-web-app
    persistence-path=""
    jsp-cache-directory="./persistence"
    jsp-cache-tlds="standard"
    simple-jsp-mapping="false"
    temporary-directory="./temp"
    servlet-webdir="/servlet/"
    >

    <web-app-class-loader search-local-classes-first="true"/>

</orion-web-app>
```

maven pom.xml

```
    <!-- JAXB implemetation by EclipseLink MOXy-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Specific dependencies for OC4J v1013 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```